# How does spark DAG works when joining two derived dataframe from a same parent one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let say I have some kind of transformation as the below snippet where i want to join two data frames derived from the very same parent one in spark. How would the DAG be optimized or not for those computing and is a persist on the initial read value of any use ?

```
val dataFrame = readDataframe() // .persist() ?
val derived1 = dataFrame.transform(/* tranformation1 */)
val derived2 = dataFrame.transform(/* tranformation2 */)
val result = derived1.join(derived2, /* condition*/)
result.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`persist` is not useful here because there is no actual operation done throughout your code due to lazy evaluation. The physical plan below shows that `persist`ing doesn't optimize the physical plan at all.

However, if you call something like `.count()` or `.show()` during the transformation, then you force Spark to evaluate your query, and `persist` will be helpful in this case.

**Without persist:**

```
scala> val df = spark.range(10)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> val df1 = df.transform(x => x.select($"id", $"id" * 2))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: bigint, (id * 2): bigint]

scala> val df2 = df.transform(x => x.select($"id", $"id" + 2))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: bigint, (id + 2): bigint]

scala> val result = df1.join(df2, "id")
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, (id * 2): bigint ... 1 more field]

scala> result.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#8L, (id * 2)#15L, (id + 2)#18L]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#8L], [id#21L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Project [id#8L, (id#8L * 2) AS (id * 2)#15L]
   :  +- *(2) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=24)
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false])), [id=#39]
      +- *(1) Project [id#21L, (id#21L + 2) AS (id + 2)#18L]
         +- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=24)
```

**With persist:**

```
scala> val df0 = df.persist()
df0: df.type = [id: bigint]

scala> val df1 = df0.transform(x => x.select($"id", $"id" * 2))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: bigint, (id * 2): bigint]

scala> val df2 = df0.transform(x => x.select($"id", $"id" + 2))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [id: bigint, (id + 2): bigint]

scala> val result = df1.join(df2, "id")
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, (id * 2): bigint ... 1 more field]

scala> result.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#8L, (id * 2)#50L, (id + 2)#53L]
+- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [id#8L], [id#56L], Inner, BuildRight
   :- *(2) Project [id#8L, (id#8L * 2) AS (id * 2)#50L]
   :  +- *(2) ColumnarToRow
   :     +- InMemoryTableScan [id#8L]
   :           +- InMemoryRelation [id#8L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
   :                 +- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=24)
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false])), [id=#100]
      +- *(1) Project [id#56L, (id#56L + 2) AS (id + 2)#53L]
         +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
            +- InMemoryTableScan [id#56L]
                  +- InMemoryRelation [id#56L], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                        +- *(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=24)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I edited my question since i feel there was still some space for interpretation

Comment: in the edited case, `persist` is useful if there are further operations on the dataframe after `show`. But if there's nothing after `show`, `persist` is not useful.